# Adjusting the bar's width in jfreechart library... How?

Tags: java, api, jfreechart

I have an (x,y) dataset of floats that spans the x-interval [0,1].  I need to render my data as bars.  However, the bars are drawn with constant width and overlay on top of each other.  I read other posts saying it is impossible to change the bars' width.  I almost gave up and then I saw an example 
HistogramDemo1.java, where the bars do adjust to a proper width.

What classes to I need to extend to get a control of bars' width within the JfreeChart library.  Currently, I am using XYPlot and XYBarRenderer for graphing.

Comment: Try [`setItemMargin()`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjfreechart%5d%20setItemMargin); if this is not a duplicate, please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that shows your revised approach.